How can i make Neovim clangd LSP use Homebrew gcc
I have Apple clang, as well as homebrew gcc installed. In neovim, i have set up the clangd lsp, which works fine as it is, but when i try to use bits/stdc++.h library, i get linting errors everywhere.
For reference, this is my neovim config: https://github.com/AnshUjlayan/nvim
I created a new std file here: /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h
my include file points here: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream (i think is supposed to be inside clitools/usr, idk why it ponts here, theres also no include files for cpp in my usr folder, i have reinstalled xcode cli tools multiple times but no fix)
when i open it in vscode, theres no linting issue, all imports are valid, i can even run it (using clang and gcc both, but the library imports are from apple clang)
this is my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Linting errors in nvim:
nvim bits/stdc++.h linting error
I fixed this issue a long time ago, by deleting the clangd binary inside ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin, and creating a symlink to /usr/bin/clangd. this resolved the issue. but when i updated the mac, i got the same linting errors. So i repeated the same steps again, now i have a different problem, idk what cpp standard it’s using this time:
nvim linting error
in vscode, no linting errors but running gave issues:
[Running] cd "/Users/anshujlayan/Documents/CodeForces/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/anshujlayan/Documents/CodeForces/"main
main.cpp:9:15: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<long long>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
  vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
              ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:8: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  for (auto i : vec)
       ^
main.cpp:10:15: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  for (auto i : vec)
              ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.513 seconds

this works, but i wanted to know if there is a way i can use stdcpp

Homebrew gcc is just a clang alias. As you can see the changes you made in c_cpp_properties.json do not affect the compilation command g++ main.cpp -o main. This is because you did not follow the official guide that pretty clearly talks about tasks.json as a location of build settings.

bits/stdc++.h is a non-standard header which is not portable between gcc and clang. Why do you want to use it (especially when using a clang-based tool)?

@HighCommander4 I am aware that bits/stdc++.h is not a standard library, but it comes with homebrew gcc, also i placed the bits/std file here: /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h
i just wanted to know of i could possibly make homebrew gcc my default on my mac whenever i run a c/cpp file (without setting alias). Or if i could configure my Neovim clangd LSP to be able to find the stdc++ file. And use std=20.

@3CxEZiVlQ I’m aware of the alias, i use g++-14 when i want to run using homebrew gcc. I don’t want to fix the vscode LSP as i don’t really use vscode.
